# Game Sprite Editting Help(PNG-XNB)

Tags: 2d, textures

I converted my project's .xnb files to .png files using a program and I can't seem to find a way to transform .png back to .xnb. I don't want to lose the work I've done. How can I change the images back?

P.S. GXView shows an error when I try to save as .xnb

Comment: why don't you use xna standard convertor/compiler?

Answer (score 8):

You can convert PNGS to XNBs by adding them to your content project in your XNA solution. You do this by right-clicking on the content project in the project explorer (right side) in Visual Studio and choosing Add->Existing. Now each time you build the solution (F5) the XNB files are created.

As far as I know you can not (easily) manually create XNB files from PNGs (or other assets) because XNB files are associated with a specific game, XNB files are a sort of protected/compressed archive for a series of assets and thus can contain more than 1 file.

About GXView, I don't know that program, but if you think that software could help you, but gives an error, could you post the error message, maybe we can help you out.

Comment: +1 @Alex: I'm not sure what the format specifications are for XNB but essentially if it is an archive or contains any extra metadata the *answer* is unfortunately *no* as PNGs will not have these and therefore that data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do here. Are you modding an XNA based game such as Terraria? Anyways check [XNA 4.0 Content Compiler](https://github.com/xupefei/XNA-4.0-Content-Compiler).